# Can I Shuffle Audio Files With SOX

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, raspberry-pi, sox

I am using this command on my raspberry pi:

```
sox -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/ribo.mp3  -t wav -  | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5 -audio -
```

Basically, it takes all the mp3 files in a directory and changes them to wav files on-the-fly, and then pipes that wav output to pifm. Is there something I can add in that would have it shuffle the files, instead of playing straight through the directory in order?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

sox -R -t mp3 /home/pi/Desktop/ribo.mp3  -t wav -  | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -freq 94.5 -audio -

the -R in the beggining shuffles the files.